# How to transform a object with keys of array into breakdown object with keys with no array

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a array of students. Each students may have mulitple address (array)  and multiple hobbies (array)

Structure as below:

```
const studentsList = {
  students: [
    {
      id: '54654',
      name: 'Tony',
      address: [
        {
          location: 'SNG',
          building: 2,
        },
        {
          location: 'LON',
          building: 3,
        },
      ],
      hobbies: [
        {
          name: 'soccer',
          id: 123,
        },
        {
          name: 'music',
          id: 53,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '505389',
      name: 'Stephen Strange',
      address: [
        {
          location: 'LUX',
          building: 8,
        },
        {
          location: 'HK',
          building: 25,
        },
      ],
      hobbies: [
        {
          name: 'watch tv',
          id: 143,
        },
        {
          name: 'music',
          id: 83,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '34534389',
      name: 'Wanda Maximoff',
      address: [
        {
          location: 'HKG',
          building: 89,
        },
        {
          location: 'GEN',
          building: 79,
        },
      ],
      hobbies: [
        {
          name: 'reading',
          id: 45,
        },
        {
          name: 'chess',
          id: 37,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

I would like to transform the student List to below format

**1. Each student has a key of hobbies and each hobbies become a single hobby instead of a array**

**2. Each student has No key of address anymore, but has a key of loccation and building instead.**

Like below

```
const studentsList = {
  students: [
    {
      id: '54654',
      name: 'Tony',
      location: 'SNG',
      building: 2,
      hobbies:  {
          name: 'soccer',
          id: 123,
        },
    },
    {
      id: '54654',
      name: 'Tony',
      location: 'LON',
      building: 3,
      hobbies:  {
          name: 'soccer',
          id: 123,
        },
    },
    {
      id: '54654',
      name: 'Tony',
      location: 'SNG',
      building: 2,
      hobbies:  {
          name: 'music',
          id: 53,
        },
    },

    {
      id: '54654',
      name: 'Tony',
      location: 'LON',
      building: 3,
      hobbies:  {
          name: 'music',
          id: 53,
        },
    },



    {
      id: '505389',
      name: 'Stephen Strange',
      location: 'LUX',
      building: 8,
      hobbies: {
          name: 'watch tv',
          id: 143,
        },
    }, 
    {
      id: '505389',
      name: 'Stephen Strange',
      location: 'HK',
      building: 25,
      hobbies: {
          name: 'watch tv',
          id: 143,
        },
    }, 
    {
      id: '505389',
      name: 'Stephen Strange',
      location: 'HK',
      building: 25,
      hobbies: {
          name: 'music',
          id: 83,
        },
    }, 
    {
      id: '505389',
      name: 'Stephen Strange',
      location: 'LUX',
      building: 8,
      hobbies: {
          name: 'music',
          id: 83,
        },
    }, 
    {
      id: '34534389',
      name: 'Wanda Maximoff',
      location: 'HKG',
      building: 89,
      hobbies:{
          name: 'reading',
          id: 45,
        },

   },
   {
      id: '34534389',
      name: 'Wanda Maximoff',
      location: 'GEN',
      building: 79,
      hobbies:{
          name: 'reading',
          id: 45,
        },

   },
   {
      id: '34534389',
      name: 'Wanda Maximoff',
      location: 'HKG',
      building: 89,
      hobbies:{
          name: 'chess',
          id: 37,
        },

   }, 
   {
      id: '34534389',
      name: 'Wanda Maximoff',
      location: 'GEN',
      building: 79,
      hobbies:{
          name: 'chess',
          id: 37,
        },

   }
  ],
}
```

Comment: And what will it give you? Growth of an object with data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some crazy functional approach using `Array::reduce()` and `Array::forEach()`.
Basically you iterate hobbies for each student and inside the loop you add each address of the student to a new student item with the current hobby and student:

```js
const students = studentsList.students
    .reduce((r, { hobbies, address, ...stud }) =>
        hobbies.forEach(hobby => address.forEach(
            addr => r.push(Object.assign({}, stud, addr, {hobbies: hobby}))
        )) || r,
    []);
  
console.log(JSON.stringify({students}, null, 4));
```

```html
<script>
const studentsList = {
  students: [
    {
      id: '54654',
      name: 'Tony',
      address: [
        {
          location: 'SNG',
          building: 2,
        },
        {
          location: 'LON',
          building: 3,
        },
      ],
      hobbies: [
        {
          name: 'soccer',
          id: 123,
        },
        {
          name: 'music',
          id: 53,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '505389',
      name: 'Stephen Strange',
      address: [
        {
          location: 'LUX',
          building: 8,
        },
        {
          location: 'HK',
          building: 25,
        },
      ],
      hobbies: [
        {
          name: 'watch tv',
          id: 143,
        },
        {
          name: 'music',
          id: 83,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '34534389',
      name: 'Wanda Maximoff',
      address: [
        {
          location: 'HKG',
          building: 89,
        },
        {
          location: 'GEN',
          building: 79,
        },
      ],
      hobbies: [
        {
          name: 'reading',
          id: 45,
        },
        {
          name: 'chess',
          id: 37,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
</script>
```

The OP asked why `Object.assign()` instead of the spread syntax. Well, my guess the spread syntax involves spread arguments (as the implementation) which are slow (you can actually get something like Maximum call stack / arguments number reached).

In our case the rest syntax is 10x slower:

[image]

```html
    <script benchmark data-count="30000">
    const studentsList = {
      students: [
        {
          id: '54654',
          name: 'Tony',
          address: [
            {
              location: 'SNG',
              building: 2,
            },
            {
              location: 'LON',
              building: 3,
            },
          ],
          hobbies: [
            {
              name: 'soccer',
              id: 123,
            },
            {
              name: 'music',
              id: 53,
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: '505389',
          name: 'Stephen Strange',
          address: [
            {
              location: 'LUX',
              building: 8,
            },
            {
              location: 'HK',
              building: 25,
            },
          ],
          hobbies: [
            {
              name: 'watch tv',
              id: 143,
            },
            {
              name: 'music',
              id: 83,
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: '34534389',
          name: 'Wanda Maximoff',
          address: [
            {
              location: 'HKG',
              building: 89,
            },
            {
              location: 'GEN',
              building: 79,
            },
          ],
          hobbies: [
            {
              name: 'reading',
              id: 45,
            },
            {
              name: 'chess',
              id: 37,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    }
    
    // @benchmark Object.assign
    studentsList.students
        .reduce((r, { hobbies, address, ...stud }) =>
            hobbies.forEach(hobby => address.forEach(
                addr => r.push(Object.assign({}, stud, addr, {hobbies: hobby}))
            )) || r,
        []);
    
        // @benchmark spread
    studentsList.students
        .reduce((r, { hobbies, address, ...stud }) =>
            hobbies.forEach(hobby => address.forEach(
                addr => r.push({...stud, ...addr, hobbies: hobby})
            )) || r,
        []);
    
    </script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is the cleanest one by far. 
May I ask what null and 4 are for in console.log(JSON.stringify({students}, null, 4));

Comment: may i ask why cant we use r.push({ stud, addr, {hobbies: hobby}})) without using asssign directly and why || r here?

Comment: @user21357723 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify . null - omit the replacer function, 4 - indent JSON with 4 spaces. if you output directly in the console without JSON you will get products displayed as references, not objects...

Comment: @user21357723 i'm a performance maniac `r.push({ ...stud, ...addr, {hobbies: hobby}}))` is slow, on the other hand `Object.assign()` is extremely fast

Comment: @user21357723 `|| r` isn't very good actually, it's returning `r` from the callback since `r.push()` is `undefined`. you could write `; return r;` but that would require `{}` brackets for the function body, so i've cheated 

Comment: Yes, one last question, may i know why object.assign is faster? if possible, can I see some related article?

Comment: Thanks a lot man, just one more question then I am done, where I can access this tool like the one you did the speed test. and just wonder where you get this extra knowledge from

Comment: @user21357723 that's my tool https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark

Answer (score 1):

```js
const studentsList = {
  students: [
    {
      id: '54654',
      name: 'Tony',
      address: [
        {
          location: 'SNG',
          building: 2,
        },
        {
          location: 'LON',
          building: 3,
        },
      ],
      hobbies: [
        {
          name: 'soccer',
          id: 123,
        },
        {
          name: 'music',
          id: 53,
        },
      ],
    },
    // ... other student objects ...
  ],
};

const transformedStudentList = {
  students: []
};

studentsList.students.forEach(student => {
  student.address.forEach(address => {
    student.hobbies.forEach(hobby => {
      transformedStudentList.students.push({
        id: student.id,
        name: student.name,
        location: address.location,
        building: address.building,
        hobbies: {
          name: hobby.name,
          id: hobby.id
        }
      });
    });
  });
});

console.log(transformedStudentList);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the working logic :**

```js
const studentsList = {
  students: [
    {
      id: "54654",
      name: "Tony",
      address: [
        {
          location: "SNG",
          building: 2,
        },
        {
          location: "LON",
          building: 3,
        },
      ],
      hobbies: [
        {
          name: "soccer",
          id: 123,
        },
        {
          name: "music",
          id: 53,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: "505389",
      name: "Stephen Strange",
      address: [
        {
          location: "LUX",
          building: 8,
        },
        {
          location: "HK",
          building: 25,
        },
      ],
      hobbies: [
        {
          name: "watch tv",
          id: 143,
        },
        {
          name: "music",
          id: 83,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: "34534389",
      name: "Wanda Maximoff",
      address: [
        {
          location: "HKG",
          building: 89,
        },
        {
          location: "GEN",
          building: 79,
        },
      ],
      hobbies: [
        {
          name: "reading",
          id: 45,
        },
        {
          name: "chess",
          id: 37,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

function builder(StudentsList) {
  let arr = StudentsList.students;
  let curr = [];

  //

  for (let elem of arr) {
    let address = elem.address;
    let hobbies = elem.hobbies;

    //if hobbies array is empty the terniary operator logic is used
    for (let itemHobbies of hobbies.length > 0
      ? hobbies
      : [{ name: null, id: null }]) {
      for (let itemAddress of address) {
        let temp = {};
        //
        temp.id = elem.id;
        temp.name = elem.name;
        //
        temp.location = itemAddress.location;
        temp.building = itemAddress.building;
        //handling if hobbies array is empty
        if (itemHobbies && itemHobbies.id == null) temp.hobbies = [];
        else temp.hobbies = itemHobbies;
        //

        curr.push(temp);
      }
    }
  }

  return curr;
}

let result = builder(studentsList);

console.log(result);
```